# What's difference between promise then and binding in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am wondering what is difference between those two services in AngularJS. In both there is promise and basicly both works.

Method with self variable:

```
module.exports = function () {
var self = this,
    data = false;

self.someFunction = function () {
    methodFromAnotherService().then(function (reponse) {
        data = response;
    });
};
};
```

Method with binding:

```
module.exports = function () {
var data = false;

this.someFunction = function () {
    methodFromAnotherService().then(function (reponse) {
        data = response;
    }.bind(this));
};
};
```

The secound one doesn't work without binding. I know that this have something to do with scope. Please provide any usefull information about major differences.

Comment: Can you put the plunkr? Not sure what function is being called

Comment: You aren't showing what `do stuff` contains. That would be the problem area because `this` would have different scope inside `then`

Comment: @charlietfl could this edit helps? I think scope is good lead. Could you explain please why self works?

Answer (score 1):

The Promise object is used for deferred and asynchronous computations. A Promise represents an operation that hasn't completed yet, but is expected in the future.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind